# Running animated x3d files Locally

Tags: html, converters, x3d, x3dom

I have this code which is an HTML page embedded with an x3d object that rotates. Everything works fine in a web browser but If i try to take the x3d section of the code and save it as an x3d file the object doesn't run in BS contact.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <title>Rotate Object</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/src/x3dom.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/src/x3dom.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
  <X3D width="500px" height="500px">
  <scene>   
    <transform DEF='couch'>
        <Transform translation='0.0 0.0 3.0'>

      <Shape DEF='leg'>
<Appearance>
<Material diffuseColor='0.2 0.1 0.0'/>
</Appearance> 
<Cylinder height='0.5' radius='0.2'/>
</Shape>
</Transform> 
<Transform translation='0.0 0.0 -3.0'>
<Shape USE='leg'/>
</Transform> 
<Transform translation='-2.0 0.0 -3.0'>
<Shape USE='leg'/>
</Transform> 
<Transform translation='-2.0 0.0 3.0'>
<Shape USE='leg'/>
</Transform> 
<Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 0.1' translation='-1.0 0.3 0.0'>
<Shape>
<Appearance>
<Material diffuseColor='0.1 0.2 0.5'/>
</Appearance> 
<Box size='2.5 0.5 7.0'/>
</Shape>
</Transform> 
<Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 0.1' translation='-1.0 0.5 3.5'>
<Group DEF='arm'>
<Shape>
<Appearance>
<Material diffuseColor='0.1 0.2 0.5'/>
</Appearance> 
<Box size='2.5 0.3 0.3'/>
</Shape> 
<Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 -1.5' translation='0.0 0.2 0.0'>
<Shape>
<Appearance>
<Material diffuseColor='0.1 0.2 0.5'/>
</Appearance> 
<Cylinder height='3.0' radius='0.2'/>
</Shape>
</Transform>
</Group>
</Transform> 
<Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 -1.4' translation='-1.0 0.7 3.5'>
<Shape DEF='woodarm'>
<Appearance>
<Material diffuseColor='0.2 0.1 0.0'/>
</Appearance> 
<Cylinder height='3.2' radius='0.1'/>
</Shape>
</Transform> 
<Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 -1.4' translation='-1.0 0.7 -3.5'>
<Shape USE='woodarm'/>
</Transform> 
<Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 0.1' translation='-1.0 0.5 -3.5'>
<Group USE='arm'/>
</Transform> 
<Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 0.4' translation='-2.2 0.8 0.0'>
<Shape>
<Appearance>
<Material diffuseColor='0.1 0.2 0.5'/>
</Appearance> 
<Box size='0.3 1.5 6.5'/>
</Shape>
</Transform> 
<Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 0.1' translation='-1.0 0.4 0.0'>
<Shape>
<Appearance>
<Material diffuseColor='0.1 0.2 0.5'/>
</Appearance> 
<Box size='2.5 0.5 6.5'/>
</Shape> 
<Transform rotation='1.0 0.0 0.0 1.5707964' translation='1.15 0.0 0.0'>
<Shape>
<Appearance>
<Material diffuseColor='0.1 0.2 0.5'/>
</Appearance> 
<Cylinder height='6.5' radius='0.25'/>
</Shape>
</Transform>
</Transform>
 
    <timeSensor DEF='clock' cycleInterval='8' loop='true'></timeSensor>
    <orientationInterpolator DEF='spinThings' key='0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1' keyValue='0 1 0 0  0 1 0 1.57079  0 1 0 3.14159  0 1 0 4.71239  0 1 0 6.28317'></orientationInterpolator>
 
    <ROUTE fromNode='clock' fromField='fraction_changed' toNode='spinThings' toField='set_fraction'></ROUTE>
    <ROUTE fromNode='spinThings' fromField='value_changed' toNode='couch' toField='set_rotation'></ROUTE>
  </scene>
  </X3D>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is to get this code to run as a local x3d file instead of an html file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [GPAC framework](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/) (Osmo4 player) to run your x3d file. I have tested the file and it works. Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- X3D Scene Dump - GPAC version 0.5.2-DEV-rev285-g6a5270d-master -->
<!DOCTYPE X3D PUBLIC "ISO//Web3D//DTD X3D 3.0//EN" "http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.0.dtd">
<X3D xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.0.xsd" version="3.0">
<head>
<meta content="X3D File Converted/Dumped by GPAC Version 0.5.2-DEV-rev285-g6a5270d-master" name="generator"/>
</head>
 <Scene>
    <Transform DEF='couch'>
    <Transform translation='0.0 0.0 3.0'>
        <Shape DEF='leg'>
            <Appearance>
                <Material diffuseColor='0.2 0.1 0.0'/>
            </Appearance>
            <Cylinder height='0.5' radius='0.2'/>
        </Shape>
    </Transform>
    <Transform translation='0.0 0.0 -3.0'>
        <Shape USE='leg'/>
    </Transform>
    <Transform translation='-2.0 0.0 -3.0'>
        <Shape USE='leg'/>
    </Transform>
    <Transform translation='-2.0 0.0 3.0'>
        <Shape USE='leg'/>
    </Transform>
    <Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 0.1' translation='-1.0 0.3 0.0'>
        <Shape>
            <Appearance>
                <Material diffuseColor='0.1 0.2 0.5'/>
            </Appearance>
            <Box size='2.5 0.5 7.0'/>
        </Shape>
    </Transform>
    <Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 0.1' translation='-1.0 0.5 3.5'>
        <Group DEF='arm'>
            <Shape>
                <Appearance>
                    <Material diffuseColor='0.1 0.2 0.5'/>
                </Appearance>
                <Box size='2.5 0.3 0.3'/>
            </Shape>
            <Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 -1.5' translation='0.0 0.2 0.0'>
                <Shape>
                    <Appearance>
                        <Material diffuseColor='0.1 0.2 0.5'/>
                    </Appearance>
                    <Cylinder height='3.0' radius='0.2'/>
                </Shape>
            </Transform>
        </Group>
    </Transform>
    <Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 -1.4' translation='-1.0 0.7 3.5'>
        <Shape DEF='woodarm'>
            <Appearance>
                <Material diffuseColor='0.2 0.1 0.0'/>
            </Appearance>
            <Cylinder height='3.2' radius='0.1'/>
        </Shape>
    </Transform>
    <Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 -1.4' translation='-1.0 0.7 -3.5'>
        <Shape USE='woodarm'/>
    </Transform>
    <Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 0.1' translation='-1.0 0.5 -3.5'>
        <Group USE='arm'/>
    </Transform>
    <Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 0.4' translation='-2.2 0.8 0.0'>
        <Shape>
            <Appearance>
                <Material diffuseColor='0.1 0.2 0.5'/>
            </Appearance>
            <Box size='0.3 1.5 6.5'/>
        </Shape>
    </Transform>
    <Transform rotation='0.0 0.0 1.0 0.1' translation='-1.0 0.4 0.0'>
        <Shape>
            <Appearance>
                <Material diffuseColor='0.1 0.2 0.5'/>
            </Appearance>
            <Box size='2.5 0.5 6.5'/>
        </Shape>
        <Transform rotation='1.0 0.0 0.0 1.5707964' translation='1.15 0.0 0.0'>
            <Shape>
                <Appearance>
                    <Material diffuseColor='0.1 0.2 0.5'/>
                </Appearance>
                <Cylinder height='6.5' radius='0.25'/>
            </Shape>
        </Transform>
    </Transform>
 </Scene>
</X3D>
```

I don't know if that is the problem but the first `Transform` in your file is not capital t. (`<trasform>` instead of `<Transform>`)

Answer (score 0):

X3D is particular about the case and node attributes names. This is not true in X3DOM. In particular the  node does not all height and width as attributes. Besides reviewing the specification, there is full information on many of the X3D nodes at http://x3dGraphics.com/.

If you want to use either X3DOM and another X3D viewing application (like BS Contact or InstantReality), I recommend put the X3D scene content in a separate X3D file and setting things up in the HTML using an  node to include the X3D content. This process is described at http://realism.com/blog/add-x3d-your-webpage